# Haskell Parsec parsing chunks of string to map values

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a string, like

```
AA{A}{END}}
```

with given map: `fromList [("{",43),("}",44),("{END}",255),("A",65)]`,

so that desired output is:       `[65,65,43,65,44,255,44]`

It looks like searching for longest prefix in map in straight Haskell, but how do I parse it with Parsec? It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026081/haskell-parsec-adapting-oneof-to-string), but here I should return `Word8` value instead of string parsed by 'choice'.

Comment: Shouldn't your desired output be: `[65,65,43,65,44,255,44]` (that last `43` in your example should be a `44` if I'm reading this correctly)

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to write a parser that takes as input a `(Word8, Int)` tuple and returns a `Parser Word8` value.

```hs
keyValParser :: (String, Word8) -> Parser Word8
keyValParser (s,v) = try (string s) >> return v
```

The above parser uses `try` against the `string` parser because Parsec has the nasty habit of consuming matching characters even on fail. If the `try (string s)` portion is successful, it returns the `Word8` value from the tuple.

Now you can map your input list against that `keyValParser` to build the parser you're looking for:

```hs
parser :: [(String, Word8)] -> Parser [Word8]
parser = many . choice . map keyValParser
```

Running this parser using `parseTest` in GHCi yields:

```hs
> let lookup = [("{",43),("}",44),("{END}",255),("A",65)]
> parseTest (parser lookup) "AA{A}{END}}"
[65,65,43,65,44,43]
```

But wait! That's not quite right. The problem now is that `choice` stops at the first matching parser, and the string `{END}` first matches `{` and thus returns `43`. You can fix this by ordering the `lookup` values by longest text first using `sortBy (flip $ comparing (length . fst))`:

```hs
parser :: [(String, Word8)] -> Parser [Word8]
parser = many . choice . map keyValParser . sortBy (flip $ comparing (length . fst))
```

Now you get the right results:

```hs
> let lookup = [("{",43),("}",44),("{END}",255),("A",65)]
> parseTest (parser lookup) "AA{A}{END}}"
[65,65,43,65,44,255,44]
```

Comment: Thank you! So that parser with parameter was a real surprise for me. I guess, just new to parser combinators.